# reading a file in python from different directory

Tags: python

Probably a simple query.. But basically, I have data in directory `"/foo/bar/foobar.txt"`

and I am working in directory `"/some/path/read_foobar.py"`..

Now I want to read the file "foobar.txt" but rather than giving full path, I thought of adding /foo/bar/ to the path..

So, added the following at the start of read_foobar.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/foo/bar")
```

But when I try to read `open("foobar.txt","r")`, it is not able to find the file?
how do I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import os
os.chdir('/foo/bar')
f = open('foobar.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: +1. Note that this is changing the current working directory, you might want to change it back before trying to open another file from the previous working dir.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.path` is used to set the path used to look for python modules. Short of you writing some helper function that has a list of directories to search in when opening a file, I don't believe there is a standard module that provides this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

From what I gathered from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) and some quick tests, appending a path to `sys.path` will make python search in that path when you `import` a file/module, but not when `open`-ing it. Let's say we have a file called `foo.py` in `/foo/bar/`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/foo/bar/")
try:
    f = open('foo.py', 'r')
except:
    print('this did not work') # this will print

import foo # no problems here
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't. The PATH environment variable is only used by the operating system to search for **executable** files, and python uses it (along with the environment variable PYTHONPATH) to search for python modules to import.

You may want to consider setting a symbolic link to that file from your current working directory

```
ln -s /foo/bar/foobar.txt /some/path/foobar.text
```